# Having Issues Connecting To Webmail Server Using My Phpmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Have been trying to use phpmailer to send mail to my business mail purchase from monovm.com hosting provider with the below codes

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';
require 'src/POP3.php';

//Instantiation and passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.haygoldinternational.com";    
    $mail->Port       =  587;                    //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   =  true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = "office@haygoldinternational.com";                   //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = "mypassword";                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;         //Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
                                     //TCP port to connect to, use 465 for `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` above

    //Recipients
    if(isset($_POST['btnSubmit']))
    {

            $mail->setFrom('office@haygoldinternational.com', 'HAYGOLD');
            $mail->addAddress('office@haygoldinternational.com', 'HAYGOLD');     //Add a recipient
            $mail->addReplyTo("toheebabiodun03@gmail.com", "Abiodun");
    
            //Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
            $mail->Subject = "TESTING";
            $mail->Body    = "Just testing";
            $mail->send();
            echo 'Message Sent Successfully';
        
    }
    
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

the error i keep getting is this

```
2021-04-03 15:37:28 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 us2.outbound.mailhostbox.com ESMTP Postfix
2021-04-03 15:37:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO haygoldinternational.com
2021-04-03 15:37:28 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-us2.outbound.mailhostbox.com250-PIPELINING250-SIZE 41648128250-VRFY250-ETRN250-STARTTLS250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-8BITMIME250 DSN
2021-04-03 15:37:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2021-04-03 15:37:28 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2021-04-03 15:37:28 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2021-04-03 15:37:28 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2021-04-03 15:37:28 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
```

What could have been the cause,i was able to use the same code to connect my gmail which work perfectly fine..
Please help a brother

Comment: Welcome. Don't post ALLCAPS, it's considered shouting/rude

Comment: Your ports are fine. It’s failing immediately after STARTTLS, which suggests a certificate problem, most likely that your CA certificate bundle is outdated. Read the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide which has extensive discussion of how to diagnose this exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than I suggested in my comment – the server you’re connecting to is not the one you asked to connect to. You asked for `smtp.haygoldinternational.com` but connected to `us2.outbound.mailhostbox.com`. This will make certificate verification fail, exactly as it should when it detects a name mismatch.

Either change your `Host` value to match it (if it’s expected), or find out why you’re being redirected there.

Comment: I  transferred the domain name to another hosting provider which as a result restrict me from accessing my webmail,  after I created an A record I was able to access the webmail..Could it be that the set up is not complete that's why I cannot access it via my phpmailer

Comment: OK, so change `Host` to whatever your new hosting provider says to use.